# post a form inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

```
WinHandle=window.open('',winName,features);
var form1 = WinHandle.document.createElement("form");
And I have something like this 
WinHandle.form1.setAttribute("id",id);
WinHandle.form1.setAttribute("method","post");
WinHandle.form1.setAttribute("action",target);
```

When I execute this code I m geting the below script error:

```
Winhandle.form1 is null.
```

can any one please help me?

Comment: That's because using object notation (`Winhandle.form1`) requires a reference to the id. Use `form1.setAttribute` or `WinHandle.document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the form, you assigned the reference to the variable `form1`.  So, to access that reference, continue to use the variable as declared:

```
form1.setAttribute("id",id);
form1.setAttribute("method","post");
form1.setAttribute("action",target);
```

Comment: But When I exceute the above code form1.setAttribute("id",id);
  form1.setAttribute("method","post");
  form1.setAttribute("action",target); I am getting the error as PERMISSION DENIED.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting the error. Is it not possible to set the form attributes Via this way?

Comment: Can any one please suggest me the answer for the above?

Comment: That might be cross-site security restrictions.  Instead of using `window.open('', winName, features)`, you could create an empty HTML document on your domain, then open that empty document in the popup.  That way, the browser sees it as belonging to the same domain and doesn't complain about security.  You'd use `window.open('http://www.mydomainname.com/blank.html', winName, features)`